# cannot deploy azure storage using azure resource manager template with Azure Automation Account

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager, azure-automation

When I'm trying to deploy an Azure Storage resource from azure automation runbook
Here is my azure run book code

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $ResourceGroupName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $StorageAccountName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $StorageAccountKey,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $StorageFileName
)



# Authenticate to Azure if running from Azure Automation
$ServicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name "AzureRunAsConnection"
Connect-AzureRmAccount `
    -ServicePrincipal `
    -TenantId $ServicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
    -ApplicationId $ServicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
    -CertificateThumbprint $ServicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint | Write-Verbose

#Set the parameter values for the Resource Manager template
$Parameters = @{
    "storageAccountType"="Standard_GRS"
    }

# Create a new context
$Context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey

Get-AzureStorageFileContent -ShareName 'resource-templates' -Context $Context -path 'blobStorageOutput.json' -Destination 'C:\Temp'

$TemplateFile = Join-Path -Path 'C:\Temp' -ChildPath $StorageFileName

# Deploy the storage account
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -TemplateFile $TemplateFile -TemplateParameterObject $Parameters
```

I'm getting the following two kinds of error
error1:

> Get-AzureStorageFileContent : The remote server returned an error:
>   (400) Bad Request. HTTP Status Code: 400 - HTTP Error Message: One of
>   the request inputs is out of range. At line:37 char:1 +
>   Get-AzureStorageFileContent -ShareName 'resource-templates' -Context
>   ... +
>
> ```
> + CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureStorageFileContent], StorageException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> StorageException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.File.Cmdlet.GetAzureStorageFileContent
> ```

error 2:

> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : Could not find file
>   'C:\Temp\blobStorageOutput.json'. At line:42 char:1 +
>   New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupN
>   ... +
>
> ```
> + CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], FileNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
> ```

Here is my template for the azure storage:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {storageAccountType
      "": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Standard_ZRS",
        "allowedValues": [
          "Standard_LRS",
          "Standard_GRS",
          "Standard_ZRS",
          "Premium_LRS"
        ],
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Storage Account type"
        }
      },
      "location": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Location for all resources."
        }
      }
    },
    "variables": {
      "storageAccountName": "[concat('store', uniquestring(resourceGroup().id))]"
    },
    "resources": [
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "apiVersion": "2018-07-01",
        "sku": {
          "name": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]"
        },
        "kind": "StorageV2",
        "properties": {}
      }
    ],
    "outputs": {
      "storageAccountName": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[variables('storageAccountName')]"
      },
      "storageUri":{
          "type": "string",
          "value": "[reference(variables('storageAccountName')).primaryEndPoints.Blob]"

      }
    }
  }
```

How can I resolve this issue 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you also post your template here?

Comment: @JoyWang now you can see the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue on my side, make sure your  `$StorageAccountName` is lowercase. For example, in my screenshot, it should be `joystoragev2`, not `Joystoragev2`. Also make sure other parameters are all correct.

[image]

The second error looks was caused by the failure of the `Get-AzureStorageFileContent`, if fix the first error, it should also work.